# multiple ajax calls to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have an issue with AJAX calls to a servlet.
On a page i want to make multiple ajax calls to the same servlet,
but i cant get it to work as how i want:

page.jsp:

> ...
>        // Button A pressed
>
> ```
>  $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: "MatchingServlet",
>         data: matchingData_X,
>   success: function(data) {
>      $('.input_A).html(data);
>      }
> });
> ...
> // Button B pressed
> $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         url: "MatchingServlet",
>         data: matchingData_Y,
>   success: function(data) {
>      $('.input_B).html(data);
>      }
>  });
> ...
> ```

MatchingServlet.java:

> ```
> ...
> MethodA(...){
> ...
> }
>
> MethodB(...){
> ...
> }
> ```

Before this project i was used to java 6 and Spring MVC where u can do this with annotations. In this surrounding i got java 1.4.2 (migration to java 6 soonish) and no frameworks.

Main question:
How can i make those 2 ajax calls go to different servlet methods?

All the examples i found here are with only one ajax call, which goes to the doGet or doPost method. So i hope it is even possible to do what i want.

Thanks in advance,
WvdL

Comment: Can you use a parameter in the url?
url: "MatchingServlet"+"?method=A" or url: "MatchingServlet"+"?method=B"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy solution would be to add a parameter named e.g. "method" to you call to the servlet like :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MatchingServlet?method=methodA",
        data: matchingData_X,
  success: function(data) {
     $('.input_A).html(data);
     }
});
```

Then, in the servlet's doGet method itself, read the parameter and forward the call to one of the other methods.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    String method = request.getParameter("method");
  if(method.equals("methodA"){
     methodA();
  }else if (method.equals("methodB"){
     methodB();
  }else{
    throw new IllegalArgumentExcpetion("'method' parameter required, must be 'methodA' or 'methodB' !");
  }
```

}

```
MethodA(...){
...
}

MethodB(...){
...
}
```

Improvements to this basic technique could be :

- use reflection instead of if... else... to determine the method to call
- use the last segment of the path instead of a parameter for the method name : MatchingServlet/methodA

But basically, you'll have to write the dispatching logic yourself !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Made some dispatching logic of my own now. kinda the same as you have now.

Answer (score 2):

When using a servlet you will need to use either the `doGet` or `doPost` methods, however once you call these methods the implementation is up to you.  I would simply put a conditional in the `doPost` method that inkokes the desired function.  The conditional would call the appropriate method based upon a request parameter passed to the servlet.  In my example, I pass a parameter `action` to the servlet, which it then uses to discern which method to use.

```
public class MyServletextends HttpServlet {

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException {
     if(request.getParameter("action").equals("methodA"){
        methodA();
     }else if(request.getParameter("action").equals("methodB"){
        methodB();
     }
   }

   public void methodA(){}
   public void methodB(){}
}
```

In the Javascript you would just need to add the action parameter:

```
 matchingData_X.action = "methodA"; //assuming matchignData_X is an object
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MatchingServlet",
        data: matchingData_X,
  success: function(data) {
     $('.input_A).html(data);
     }
});
...
// Button B pressed
matchingData_X.action = "methodB"; //assuming matchignData_X is an object
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MatchingServlet",
        data: matchingData_Y,
  success: function(data) {
     $('.input_B).html(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. due my limit of points i cant give u credits for it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a 
`parameters: 'someParam'`
section in your ajax call then on the Servlet get the parameters from the request:

```
String param= request.getParameter("someParam");
            if (param.equals("someParam") {
                MethodA();
            }
```

Comment: This is what i'm doing now, but it doesnt seem to be the 'right' way to do it for me.

Comment: I think Pierre Henry's answer is more what you're looking for. He gives a lot more detail. This may be the key "url: "MatchingServlet?method=methodA""